# EXCEL: How can I populate VLOOKUP into various cells?

Tags: excel, function, vlookup, lookup

I have 2 spreadsheets inside a workbook:

1. Main Sheet (this is used as a document that gets printed to pdf)
2. Return Index (this is a table with 13 columns & up to 400 rows).

On the main sheet, there are various cells that need the data inputting with a header at the top - "Index Number".

I would like to create a drop down menu for "Index Number" (which is column A on sheet 2, Return Index) so that when you select the Index Number, it automatically populates the fields on sheet 1 (Main Sheet), from the data in the row from sheet 2 (Return Index).

We already have a vlookup for an address field which is fine because when you select the addressee, the address follows on the 4 columns below.

The problem I'm having is that the fields I want populating are not next to each other and are in random cells.

For company/security purposes I have provided a very basic screenshot of an example.

I've highlighted a row to hopefully show how I would like the data populated...

Main Sheet on left. Return Index on right.
PLEASE NOTE: This is for illustration purposes ... Main Sheet & Return Index will both be in the same workbook.

I hope this helps.

Thank you all.

Tim.

[image: Spreadsheet example]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`=VLOOKUP($B$1,$K$2:$U$3,2,FALSE)`

Results:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The formula for all of them will follow a similar pattern, with just the column being different:

```
=Vlookup($E$9,'Return Index'!$A$2:$M$400,2,False)
```

Them just replace the 2 with the different fields you need for each cell.

On the other hand, if the field name is always to the left of the cell where the value will be, you could use index/match and the formula could just be copy-pasted between the cells

```
=Index('Return Index'!$B$2:$M$400,Match($E$9,$A$2:$A$400,0),Match(B13,$B$1:$M$1,0))
```

Where `B13` refers to the cell to the left of the current cell.